# How can I make two refreshcontrol in two UITableView?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have made two `UITableView` in a `UIView` controller and it run smoothly. I have also two different `UIButton` to run call `reloaddata`, works fine too.

Now I would like to make two different `UIRefreshControl` into my `UIView`, I wrote below code but neither one table work. How can I make it?

Thanks~

Here my `RefreshControl` code:

```
    UIRefreshControl *refresh_tbl_task = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refresh_tbl_task.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [refresh_tbl_task addTarget:nil action:@selector(loadTasksTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially you can only add a refresh control to a UITableViewController. So you'd need to have your two table views in child view controller objects, and assign each refresh control to each child table viewcontroller.

So, rather than having two table views as subviews, you'd have the views of two table view controllers as subviews.